Issues Receiving Signal with USRP B210 in MATLAB vs Simulink
I am new to signal processing and appreciate your understanding as I seek assistance.
I am trying to receive a signal generated by a signal generator using the USRP B210, and I am working with both MATLAB and Simulink. While I am able to achieve satisfactory results with Simulink for comparison, my MATLAB script does not yield the expected results. The final goal is to run code to receive the GPS signals in Matlab.
Here are the details of my setup:

Sampling Rates: 20 Msps (MATLAB), 30 Msps (Simulink)
Carrier Frequency: 1575.42 MHz
Signal Generator Frequency: 1581.2 MHz
In Simulink, the graph displays the results I expect. However, the MATLAB script does not produce the same outcome.




Here is the MATLAB code I am using:
% Parameters
Fs = 20e6; % Sampling frequency (50 MHz)
RxFreq = 1575.42e6; % GPS L1 frequency (1575.42 MHz)
duration = 1; % Duration of signal reception (30 seconds)
NumSampsPerFrame = 2048; % Number of samples per frame
rxGain = 25; % Receiver gain (dB)

% Calculate the total number of samples to receive
totalNumSamps = duration * Fs;

% Calculate the number of frames needed
numFrames = ceil(totalNumSamps / NumSampsPerFrame);

% Initialize a buffer to store all received data
rxdata = zeros(totalNumSamps, 1);

% Set up the USRP receiver
rx = comm.SDRuReceiver( ...
    'Platform', 'B210', ...
    'SerialNum', '3218C85', ...
    'PPSSource', 'Internal', ...
    'ClockSource', 'Internal', ...
    'DecimationFactor', 16, ... % Adjust decimation if necessary
    'SamplesPerFrame', NumSampsPerFrame, ...
    'OutputDataType', 'double', ...
    'ChannelMapping', 2, ...
    'Gain', rxGain, ...
    'CenterFrequency', RxFreq);
rx
disp('Test for receiving GPS signal...');
frameData = zeros(NumSampsPerFrame,1);
[frameData, len, ~, ~] = step(rx);
disp('Data received');
disp(datetime('now'));
normalizedSamples = frameData / max(abs(frameData));
I = real(normalizedSamples);
Q = imag(normalizedSamples);

% Plot 1: I and Q components
figure;
subplot(3, 1, 1);
plot(I, 'r');
hold on;
plot(Q, 'b');
title('I and Q Components');
xlabel('Sample Index');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('I', 'Q');
hold off;

% Plot 2: Constellation Plot
subplot(3, 1, 2);
plot(I, Q, '.');
title('Constellation Plot');
xlabel('I');
ylabel('Q');
axis([-1 1 -1 1]);

% Plot 3: FFT Plot
% Select the first 2048 samples for FFT
fftSamples = normalizedSamples(1:NumSampsPerFrame);

% Compute FFT
fftResult = fftshift(fft(fftSamples));
frequencies = linspace(-Fs/2, Fs/2, NumSampsPerFrame)./1e6;

% Plot the magnitude of the FFT
subplot(3, 1, 3);
plot(frequencies, (abs(fftResult)));
title('FFT Plot');
xlabel('Frequency (MHz)');
ylabel('Magnitude');
xlim([-Fs/(2*1e6) Fs/(2*1e6)]);

% Adjust the layout
sgtitle('USRP Data Analysis');

% Release the receiver
release(rx);

% Clear the variable
clearvars rx

% Check if the release was successful
try
   disp('The USRP object has been successfully released and cleared.');
catch ME
    disp('An unexpected error occurred:');
    disp(ME.message);
end
disp('Receiving GPS signal...');
i = 1;
while i <= numFrames
    % Receive a frame of data
    if i == 1
        disp('Config');
    end
    [frameData, len, ~, ~] = step(rx);
    if i == 1
        disp('started');
    end
    if len ~= NumSampsPerFrame
        continue;
    end

    if len < 0
        warning('No data received in current frame');
    end
    
    % Store the received frame data
    startIdx = (i-1)*NumSampsPerFrame + 1;
    endIdx = min(i*NumSampsPerFrame, totalNumSamps);
    rxdata(startIdx:endIdx) = frameData(1:(endIdx-startIdx+1));
    
    % Display progress
    if mod(i, 2000) == 0 % Update every 10 frames
        disp(['Frames received: ', num2str(i), '/', num2str(numFrames)]);
    end

    i = i + 1;
end
disp('Finished receiving')
% Release the USRP object


% Plot the received signal (Real Part)
figure;
% plot((0:totalNumSamps-1)/Fs, real(rxdata));
plot(real(rxdata));
title('Received GPS Signal (Real Part)');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

Could you please help me understand why there is a discrepancy between the results in MATLAB and Simulink? What adjustments should I make to align the MATLAB script's output with the results from Simulink?
Thank you for your assistance!
Best regards,
Yonghoon

so, what does your Matlab output look like?

by the way, your simulink constellation plot suggests you are using the USRP with a gain that's too low, maybe by 13 dB. You get very few quantization levels (around 16), whereas the ADC of your device has 2¹² levels. A sensibly amplified GNSS signal would look roughly circularly-normal (Gaussian) in the complex plane.

Also, you're not at all using the sampling rate you claim to use. You forget to inform the SDR about the sampling rate you want it to do!


The matlab output is the third picture.
It seems like the usrp received the noise.
Can you explain more about the sampling rate? I thought I was using the sampling rate correctly. Correct me if I am wrong. Is it safe to think the sampling rate is the bandwidth of the FFT?


re: 3. no, it's not safe to assume that, obviously: you set the frequency axis yourself! The FFT knows nothing about the sampling rate. All it is is a mapping of N complex values to N complex values; there's only these N numbers, and no time information. The sampling rate needs to be set when creating the SDRuReceiver object.

I see what you mean. Thank you for your response.
